# How do I fix this error in Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I click on Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda Navigator, I am receiving this error. I was just using Jupyter Notebook and had no issues. I restarted my computer and now I am receiving this.

````
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\csu5141\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
    File "C:\Users\csu5141\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 44, in 
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
    File "C:\Users\csu5141\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 12, in 
    from .environment import Environment
    File "C:\Users\csu5141\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 25, in 
    from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
    File "C:\Users\csu5141\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 3, in 
    from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS # noqa: F401
    File "C:\Users\csu5141\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 13, in 
    from markupsafe import soft_unicode
    ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\Users\csu5141\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

inside environment terminal use pip install markupsafe==2.0.1

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.